# Popular obstacle avoidance techniques / algorithms

Tags: algorithm

I am working on an autonomous vehicle driving system in school, and I'm trying to look for popular / widely used obstacle avoidance algorithms / techniques, that are used by Google or Tesla, etc.

I have read about the bug algorithm, the potential field algorithm, and the VFH algorithm, but I can't really figure out if they're really used in the industry or they're just popular for being so simple.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right- they are just popular. I am an autonomous vehicle engineer and so far haven't used these algos. Actually it's not about algos anymore

In layman language: Autonomous vehicle needs to be generic enough and no generic algo can suffice for the actual real time scenario on the roads.

You might wonder the autonomous drive is already in practice in aerial and marine vehicles but not the ones on land. Because the realtime scenario on land is very complex. For instance different types of traffic signs, driving behaviors, weather and brightness conditions. This requires machine learning and image processing.

image processing and augmentation is required to train the vehicle to behave like humans in such scenarios.

Machine just learns from previous experiences and behaves in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular techniques for building Autonomous Vehicles is using Deep Reinforcement Learning algorithms (e.g. DQN, Rainbow, DDPG, PPO, etc). The advantage of DRL algorithms is that You don't have to specify or describe the behavior of the vehicle in its environment. The aim of the DRL is to found the best possible behavior for a vehicle agent. To check more about Autonomous Vehicle algorithms, check my repository here:

https://github.com/kochlisGit/autonomous-vehicles-deep-reinforcement-learning